# How can passkeys be synced when they "never leave your device"?

Tags: ios, keychain, passkey

Reading about passkeys in the iOS change log I get the impression that they're just private keys used to sign requests with, just like physical security keys:

> Passkeys never leave your device

Sounds reasonable, since the OS would only need an interface for signing — never actual read access to the key.

Then I read this:

> Passkeys are end‑to‑end encrypted and sync across your Apple devices

Uh... Obviously not, since they "never leave your device".

How does that work?

Comment: Probably just unfortunate wording on Apple's part, although they do say it in multiple documents.  I'm hoping that there ends up being third-party multi-platform support... it's not like I'd ever trust that sort of information to iCloud.

Comment: @MarcWilson "just unfortunate wording" implies an obvious explanation. Do you have it? As for third party support, I assumed this followed some existing security standard. Otherwise that's a good way of convincing me not to use it.

Comment: Sure.  They're syncing the private keys around.  I thought that was obvious.  As for third-party support, if it's only on the Mac, I won't be using it.  Well, I wouldn't be using it anyway, trusting something like that to Apple does not appeal.

Comment: @MarcWilson I had imagined that they could sync just the info needed to request a new device specific key to be associated with an account, but come to think of it that would require authorization from an existing device every time, which wouldn't be a very convenient "sync". Ok, so the keys can't be stored on any non-accessible special purpose hardware and can't be as secure as a yubikey, etc.